# Using the same view for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rails-activerecord, view-helpers

I have a "section" model and a "page" model with relative controllers and would like both to render the same view. I'm trying to get the category whether I'm rendering a page or a section.

In page, category is referenced though section.

It renders properly when linking to a section via: /sections/8

However, when linking to a page via: /pages/2

I get the error: "undefined method `category' for #" on the "if @page.category" part of the helper.

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :skin_id, :section_id, :name, :title, :content

  belongs_to :skin
  belongs_to :section
  validates_presence_of :skin
  validates_presence_of :section
end
```

section.rb

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :skin_id, :page, :name, :title, :content

  has_many :pages

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :skin

  validates_presence_of :category
  validates_presence_of :skin
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

pages_helper.rb

```
module PagesHelper

  def category
    if @page.category
      @page.category
    else 
      @page.section.category
    end
  end
end
```

page.html.haml

```
-@sections = Section.all
%nav#side
  %ul
    -@sections.each do |section|
      -if section.category == category
        %li
          = link_to section.title, section
          %ul
            -section.pages.each do |page|
              %li
                = link_to page.title, page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add 'has_one :category, :through => :section' to your page model

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :skin_id, :section_id, :name, :title, :content

  belongs_to :skin
  belongs_to :section

  has_one :category, :through => :section

  validates_presence_of :skin
  validates_presence_of :section
end
```

Next break them into partials.

Create a file called _section.html.haml in your sections folder. Then do the following

_section.html.haml

```
%li
  = link_to section.title, section
    %ul
      -section.pages.each do |page|
        %li
          = link_to page.title, page
```

then your page.html.haml

```
%nav#side
  %ul
    -@sections.each do |section|
      -if section.category == category
        = render :partial => "sections/setion", :locals => {:section => section}
```

You should now be able to reuse the sections partial and you should be able to access the category strait from the page.